# How to test a Salesforce Installhandler?

Tags: apex, postinstall, install

I have written one class for Post Installment InstallHandler. 
I also have written Test class for the same which work very fine. Run successfully with full coverage.

But Now, I suppose to be sure that this InstallHandler class will work with client/installer.

Answer (score 4):

There is a method available in the Test class, that gives you the ability to test InstallHandlers.
You create an instance of your InstallHandler class, and pass it to the `.testInstall()' method, like so.

```
@isTest
private class InstallLogicTest
{
    static testMethod void installTest()
    {
        InstallLogic postinstall = new InstallLogic();
        Test.testInstall(postinstall, new Version(1, 0), true);
    }
}
```

More information regarding the testInstall methods:
https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_test.htm#apex_System_Test_testInstall

Comment: Yes sure I did this (Test Class - for Coverage and etc), I mean to say - Do I have to create Package of everything with my InstallHandler classes and all  AND Do I have to Install in my Demo orgs to test whether this code works perfectly or not.

Comment: Normally if you write your Tests good, it shouldn't matter, but if you want to test manually by yourself, you will have to make a package (can be beta) and install it on another org (if beta, sandbox or dev- org)